# How to adjust Layout backgroud image to centerInside?

Tags: android, android-layout, scaletype

When assigning an image as a background to a Layout(Linear || Relative) it **stretched** all over the Layout, but I want to make that *background image* to be **centered inside** the Layout as in the `ImageButtons` :

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Is there's a way to achieve that in `Linear` or `Relative` Layouts?

Comment: Don't use `background`, use `src` in conjunction with `scaleType`. `background` is **always** stretched

Comment: @DerGolem there's no src option in layouts

Comment: ... and background doesn't use scaleType. In a RelativeLayout, you can use an ImageView with layout_width and layout_height = "match_parent" and then all the other controls can be overlaid on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the....

1.) take the RelativeLayout propery matchParent both. and centerInparent=true

2.) take one ImageView inside it Property WrapContent.
now take the background or src of inage view

Answer (score 1):

you can use another layout LayoutB inside the LayoutA.   and set the width and height to wrap_content of LayoutB..and set the image to background of LayoutB..and also set the arributs like this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/someImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/someImageSrc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```